# Why does $\lim_{n \to \infty} P_{X}((y-a_{n},y])=F_{X}(y)-\lim_{n \to \infty}F_{X}(y-a_{n})$?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, random-variables

I am currently working on the following problem for my measure theory class and have a question about the *hint* given:

> Show that $F_{X}$ (the cumulative distribution function of a random variable $X : \Omega \to \Bbb{R}$) is continuos if and only if $P_{X}(\{y\})=0 \ \text{(were $P_X$ is the probability distribution of the random variable $X$.)} \ \forall y.$

Where the **hint** states: *note that $\lim_{n \to \infty} P_{X}((y-a_{n},y])=F_{X}(y)-\lim_{n \to \infty}F_{X}(y-a_{n})$ for a sequence $a_n$ such that $a_n \nearrow 0$.*

My questions is why can we do the step in $\color{blue}{blue}$? $$\lim_{n \to \infty} P_{X}((y-a_{n},y])=\color{blue}{F_{X}(y)-\lim_{n \to \infty}F_{X}(y-a_{n})}.$$I understand how this hint can be used to prove that $P_{X}(\{y\})=0$, but I am unsure as to how it is formulated.

Note my definition of the CDF of a random variable is $F_{X}(y) :=P(\{\omega: X(\omega) \leq y\}) =P_{X}((-\infty,y]).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(X \in (y-a_n,y])$$ $$=P(X \in (-\infty, y])-P(X \in (-\infty, y-a_n)=F_X(y)-F_X(y-a_n).$$

[$X^{-1}(y-a_n,y]=X^{-1}(-\infty, y] \setminus X^{-1}(-\infty, y-a_n)]$ and $B \subset A$ implies $P(A\setminus B )=P(A)-P(B)$].

Comment: One question: what does the notation $P(X \in (y-a_{n},y])$ mean? I'm new to probability so I'm assuming it means $P_{X}((y-a_{n},y])$

Comment: $P(X^{-1}(A))$ is same as $P (X \in A)$. @TaylorRendon